# CSS rotation does not work properly on ios

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ios

I'm working on a wheel of fortune project. Each time someone press "spin" button, we get the prize from an api and calculate the angle based on our target gift and then rotate. In some cases, **on iphone**, after rotation the result doesn't match our target gift. Therefore I'm looking for a way to double check the result with target and keep rotating if they doesn't match. here is my rotation Javascrip functions:

```
function startRotation(target){
let giftIndex = parseInt(target.attr('id'))
angle = 360 - ((giftIndex - 1) * (360 / wheelItems.lenght)) - ((360 / wheelItems.lenght) / 3) 
angle = angle === 360 ? 0 : angle
rotate(target)}


function rotate(target) {
randomNum = angle + (1800 * ri);
ri++
$(".mainCircle").css('transform', `translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(${randomNum}deg)`)

setTimeout(() => {
    winPrize(target)
}, 7500)}
```

and here is where I add gifts to the wheel:

```
function createCircle(wheelItems){
let colors = ['#16A085', '#2989B9',  '#8E44AD', '#F39C12', '#D35400', '#C0392B', 'cyan', 'brown', 'gray', 'pink', 'maroon', 'gold']
let count = wheelItems.lenght
for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    let img = document.createElement('img')
    let text = document.createElement('span')
    text.innerHTML = wheelItems[i].title
    img.src = '/wheel/'+wheelItems[i].title;
    img.style.transform = 'skewY('+ Math.abs(90 - (360 / count)) +'deg) rotate('+ 360 / count / 2 + 'deg)'
    img.style.width = (40 - ((count - 4) * 3.125)) + '%'
    img.style.left = (34 - ((count - 4) * 1.75)) + '%'
    img.style.paddingTop = (43 + ((count - 4) * 3.25)) + '%'
    text.style.transform = 'skewY('+ Math.abs(90 - (360 / count)) +'deg) rotate('+ 360 / count / 2 + 'deg)'
    text.style.width = (50 - ((count - 4) * 3.125)) + '%'
    text.style.left = (25 - ((count - 4) * 1.75)) + '%'
    text.style.paddingTop = (75 + ((count - 4) * 3.25)) + '%'
    $('<li>')
        .css({'transform': 'rotate(' + i * (360 / count) + 'deg) skewY(-' + Math.abs(90 - (360 / count)) + 'deg)', 'background' : colors[i]})
        .appendTo('ul.mainCircle')
        .addClass('item' + i)
        .append(img)
        .append(text)
}}
```

I already tried to check the overlap between pin element and the target gift element (`<li>`) but apparently the `<li>` elements overlap each other so the result is not always accurate. I also tried to find a way to calculate the angle difference of the wheel after rotation, but I couldn't find one that does not use the css `transform rotate` value.

I would really appreciate it if you can help me find a way to make sure this problem doesn't happen again.

thanks

Comment: Do you mean lenght everywhere rather than length? Perhaps you could make a runnable snippet so we could see the problem for ourselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example And are you saying it works on other systems? Could you tell us which ones you have tried?

Comment: Dear @AHaworth, yes, sorry I meant length. yes it works on other systems, I've tried chrome and firefox, apparently the problem only appears on iphone.  forgive me I can't make a runnable snippet for now.